# Equal width in percentages using table-cell

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/hw98P/

While this is not a huge deal, it bothers me to not know why this behavior is happening. I have 3 divs set as table-cells. What I want is the left col at 20% and the middle and right cols to be at 40%, after padding has been added into that. I changed my px padding to percentages and have allotted for that difference in my calculations, but the middle and right cells are not the same width. The middle shows 482px and the right shows 508px.

My question is why is this happening? Is it possible to get the middle and right cols exactly the same width?

```
  #content {
  padding:15px 0;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  }

  #content #col1 {
  border-right:1px solid #E2E2E2;
  padding-right:1%;
  width:19%;
  display:table-cell;
  }

  #content #col2 {
  border-right:1px solid #E2E2E2;
  padding-right:1%;
  padding-left:1%;
  width:38%;
  display:table-cell;
  }

  #content #col3 {
  width:39%;
  padding-left:1%;
  display:table-cell;
  }

<div id="content">
  <div id="col1">1</div>
  <div id="col2">2</div>
  <div id="col3">3</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I have also tried setting `table-layout: fixed;` on `#col1` but this changes nothing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/hw98P/11/ works for you?

Comment: I get 161, 156 and 162. :(

Comment: are you seeing in chrome or in FF?

Comment: In FF. I don't use Chrome, although I should

Comment: I am also fan of FF. :)

Comment: Cool. I thought I was the only one left. :)

Comment: Are you using anything to reset or normalize the css? In fiddle options, check normalize css, I'm on my phone but the body padding in ff may be the culprit

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/hw98P/14/ check the updated DEMO. are you getting equal width now?

Comment: @KheemaPandey, thanks for the fiddle. All cols are exactly even. I am seeing 167px on each column

Comment: @NaN is my DEMO helpful for you. just curious?

Answer (score 1):

It is all because of width calculation. So try to use box-sizing property. Update your CSS like below. [More Information about box-sizing property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

```
  #content {
  padding:15px 0;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  }

  #content #col1 {
  border-right:1px solid #E2E2E2;
  padding-right:1%;
  width:20%;
  display:table-cell;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }

  #content #col2 {
  border-right:1px solid #E2E2E2;
  padding-right:1%;
  padding-left:1%;
  width:40%;
  display:table-cell;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }

  #content #col3 {
  width:40%;
  padding-left:1%;
  display:table-cell;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/hw98P/7/)

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this but the cols are still not equal.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle. I just tried it and the cols are about 20px off.

Comment: Isn't that weird? I don't understand why not. I'm not a stranger to CSS and your example should work. I wonder if it's a bug?

Comment: Try `*, *:before, *:after{ box-sizing: border-box} ` to ensure all elements react the same and `body, html{margin:0; padding:0}` to reset the body and :root

Comment: @darcher, actually, I already tried that. In fact, the code I used was exactly what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible. You can use the calc() CSS3 function which should make your measurements to your standard.

```
Example:

.style{
width:calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

Example explained: So lets say the my screen width resolution is 1000px the value 50% holds is 500px. This value is then taken 10px away from. The final value will give you for 490px for the width.

More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

If you have any questions or this did not help, please comment back or contact me.

Comment: Thanks IP. I'm going to try this now. BTW, I used to HATE CSS until CSS3 came out, now I love it.

Comment: Hey, IP? This still isn't giving me equal columns. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you my friend. I'm truly at a loss. I've also changed the px designation to em and it's still off by about 15 px.

Comment: OK, that's perfect and shows perfectly even columns, however, I need to use table-cells because of the vertical borders that separate the columns and they need to grow with the tallest column. I've never been able to achieve this behavior with anything else

Comment: @NaN then friend i think you should use the <hr> element and make that float left also and then change the width using calc. I will upload some code

Comment: Thank you, IP. I'm kind of lost on how you're telling me to do this.

Comment: @NaN try this http://jsfiddle.net/hw98P/13/ If you need to add other things such as padding add them but remember to minus it is the calc funtion for the width. Sorry if you dont understand me but feel free to contact me if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you IP. I understand you perfectly, I'm just not as good with CSS as you are. :) I'll have a look at your code now. Thank you again!

Comment: I just tried this. Thank you again, IP. Maybe I am missing something but when I use some text in the middle col, cols1 and 3 do not grow with the content in col2. Am I doing somehting wrong?

Comment: Oh yeah, and, I also made the `hr` tag 100% height

Comment: @NaN You are not doing anything wrong. Is the hr tag filling the container when it is 100%. And the background color shouldnt increase size if you write in the middle column unless you add more css

Comment: I put some text in the middle column (col2) and the green background grows with the content. Cols 1 and 3 stay static and do not show any change at all. Should I have a 100% declaration on html, body as well? I do not right now.

Comment: @NaN I think you can add height to the col 1-3 so that they can fill up and not stay static. Try height:100%; or height:inherit;

Comment: I just added height:100%; to the columns but the other columns do not grow with the content.

Comment: @NaN I am really sorry but I dont know what i can do there. But if you are having no background color to the columns you could just give the background color to the container. pls message back if you need more help and i will try to help you out

Comment: Thank you my friend. I truly appreciate you trying to help me here. If nobody provides a working answer by tomorrow, I'll credit you for this one. You earned it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I've used `box-sizing: border-box;` and using of `pseudo element` all innderdiv width are equal now. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/hw98P/14/)**.

```
#content {
  padding:15px 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
#content div{   
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}

  #content #col1 {
  display:table-cell;
  background:gold;
  position:relative;  
  }

#content #col2:after, #content #col3:before{
position: absolute;
content: " ";
top:0;
left:0;
display:block;
width: inherit;
}


  #content #col2 {
  display:table-cell;
  background:green;
  position:relative;
  }

  #content #col3 {
  display:table-cell;
  background:yellow;
  position:relative;   
  }
```

Comment: Kheema, I just tried your code and unfortunately, all of the columns are exactly 167px. What I need is the left column at 20% and the middle and right columns at 40%, for a total of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain your code structure (by this I mean use `table`/`table-cell`), here's a better approach with the same concept: http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/hw98P/23/

**BUT**

To start, You have multiple options here to achieve what you need. `position`, `table-cell`, `float`, and `flexbox`. I've used all four in this [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/hw98P/22/). They have varying levels of support, so make sure you research the best option for you (you can check [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) for this). **I recommend `float`'s as it's tried and true**; however, `flexbox` is certainly picking up speed.

### Onto your OP

The cause is *probably* the use of uneven paddings for each cell in conjunction with % width and right borders.

*Disclaimer: Now, admittedly, I'm unsure of all the factors for the various browsers rendering of `display:table`.*

- I'm very inclined to believe it's the way you have structured the css and how the cells are inheriting padding, most specifically the order in which they're rendering.

I don't have an exact answer as to why, but I do have a solution. You can rework it using left borders and like paddings *or* clearing the left/right most paddings after declaring like paddings. You should attempt to be as consistent as possible when developing layout based code for factors ranging from scalability to error reduction and compatibility, it's just good practice. *You can probably override the differing paddings structure by way of relatively positioning the cells, but I don't see a reason for the extra mark-up or time when there's a simple solution that promotes cleaner, better structured approaches.*

1) Bear in mind there are limitations in support for `calc()`: http://caniuse.com/calc, you can use `box-shadow:-1px 0 1px -1px #eee` to avoid the 1px  `border-width` and avoid using `calc()` altogether, but it too has its limitations: http://caniuse.com/box-shadow.

2) The `border-box` needs to be prefixed (even still) in order for this to react the same in Mozilla as it does in Chrome. While using this method, the browser calculates the `padding` and `border-width` into the element width for you. If you use the below you won't require `calc()` or offsetting your widths from your paddings. http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

**How I'd do it:** If I *HAD* to use `display:table`

```
*,*:before,*:after{/* 2 */
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box}

.content {
    display:table;
    padding:15px 0;
    width:100% }

div[class^=col] {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:0 15px }

.col1 { width:20%; } 
.col2, .col3{ 
    box-shadow:-1px 0 1px -1px grey; /* 1 */
    width:40% }
```

Comment: Darcher, thank you for all if your help and the effort you put into this. Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. There is no additional CSS that could possibly be making this not work, because what I posted is all of the CSS I have. I am using FF v30, and it does not understand the `calc` function. In fact, I can get closer to my percentages if I remove `calc` from the CSS. Weird..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, here are 4 additional methods that work http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/hw98P/22/ ---

and here is a remake of what you did that also works http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/hw98P/23/
 --- 
All in FFv30, I'm not even using `calc()` in the fiddles. I've tested them all. Your intention was to have the same width in the last two cols. Which these all do.